# Resharper code contract doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Lets say that I have these two methods used for asserting and logging failed assertions:

```
[ContractAnnotation("condition: false => halt")]
public static void AssertCondition(bool condition, string errorMessage = StringUtil.Empty)
{
    if (!condition)
    {
        Logger.Log("AssertCondition failed " + errorMessage, Level.Error);
        throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
    }
}

[ContractAnnotation("condition: null => halt")]
public static void AssertNotNull(object condition, string errorMessage = StringUtil.Empty)
{
    if (condition == null)
    {
        Logger.Log("AssertNotNull failed" + errorMessage, Level.Error);
        throw new ArgumentNullException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

If I have a method like this in my MVC controller:

```
public string Test()
{
    return Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
}
```

I get NPE warning from ReSharper. If I use the first assert method like this:

```
public string Test()
{
    Preconditions.AssertCondition(Request.Url != null);
    return Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
}
```

I don't get a NPE warning, which is completely expected and working as designed. But if use the second assert, the one specifying that it halts if argument is null (`null => halt`), I still get NPE warning:

```
public string Test()
{
    Preconditions.AssertNotNull(Request.Url);
    return Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
}
```

The code above warns me as if there was no assert in there at all. What did I do wrong? As far as I can tell from the docs and tutorials I read, this should be working.

Comment: Question is not 100% clear to me, but if I get it correctly - using `AssertCondition` you do not receive NPE warning, but using `AssertNotNull` you do, right? I tried to reproduce your problem and everything was working for me as expected, i.e. `Preconditions.AssertNotNull(Request.Url)`displays no warning. Then I tried to modify ContractAnnotation over AssertNotNull to read `"condition: notnull => halt"` and NPE warning was displayed, just as expected... What version of R# are you on? Mine is 7.1.2

Comment: 8.1. And yes, you got it perfectly. Strange that this is happening to me. I doubt that they broke it in the latest version.